# How to compare string with `"`,`'`,`[` through PHP?

Tags: php

There's a string(95) as below:
`errornotes(join("notices(realres,response.pattern=c(", answer, "),method='QOP')[1,'N2']"), NUM)`

My php script does compare a variable with this string:

```
if($output=="errornotes(join(\"notices(realres,response.pattern=c(\", answer, \"),method='QOP')[1,'N2']\"), NUM)"){
    echo "match";
}
```

Above script work not well,where is the problem?Should add more escape character `\`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Do you get any errors?

Comment: If you can't see a difference but those strings are still not equal, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php function

Comment: @matiit.xdiff find the problem, thank  you!

Answer (score 0):

Echo the `$output` variable to check whether it matches the expected string or not.

```
echo $output;
```

There is no any issue with your code. So my best guess is, issue is with your variable.

Comment if the problem persists.